# C# - Binding TextBox to an integer

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

How to bind a TextBox to an integer? For example, binding unit to textBox1.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int unit;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", unit, "???");
    }
```

Comment: It derives from Form class.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It would need to be a public property of an instance; in this case, the "this" would suffice:

```
public int Unit {get;set;}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Unit");
}
```

For two-way notification, you'll need either `UnitChanged` or `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
private int unit;
public event EventHandler UnitChanged; // or via the "Events" list
public int Unit {
    get {return unit;}
    set {
        if(value!=unit) {
            unit = value;
            EventHandler handler = UnitChanged;
            if(handler!=null) handler(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

If you don't want it on the public API, you could wrap it in a hidden type somewhere:

```
class UnitWrapper {
    public int Unit {get;set;}
}
private UnitWrapper unit = new UnitWrapper();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", unit, "Unit");
}
```

For info, the "events list" stuff goes something like:

```
    private static readonly object UnitChangedKey = new object();
    public event EventHandler UnitChanged
    {
        add {Events.AddHandler(UnitChangedKey, value);}
        remove {Events.AddHandler(UnitChangedKey, value);}
    }
    ...
    EventHandler handler = (EventHandler)Events[UnitChangedKey];
    if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

Comment: Marc, I can't find more info about that trick when you name your event `xxxChanged` for property `xxx` and then it is handled behind the scene. Can you post a link or at least how the trick is called? Thanks

Comment: That is part of the PropertyDescriptor implementation - basically it looks for a pattern of *Changed events. However, you can also usually use INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: attributes naming trick when `xxxAttribute` class can be used then as just `xxx` is well written in msdn. But this behaviour is really hidden. I've tried to google some more info about it but failed (maybe because word 'changed' puzzles search query) :) anyway, thx again

Comment: @pkuderov the *Attribute thing is a compiler behaviour - the *Changed is applied at runtime. Other ones include things like ShouldSerialize*  - again this is applied by PropertyDescriptor

Answer (score 5):

You can use a binding source (see comment). The simplest change is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public int Unit { get; set; }
    BindingSource form1BindingSource;

    private void Form1_Load (...)
    {
        form1BindingSource.DataSource = this;
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add ("Text", form1BindingSource, "Unit");
    }
}
```

However, you'll gain some conceptual clarity if you separate out the data a bit:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    class MyData {
        public int Unit { get; set; }
    }

    MyData form1Data;
    BindingSource form1BindingSource;

    private void Form1_Load (...)
    {
        form1BindingSource.DataSource = form1Data;
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add ("Text", form1BindingSource, "Unit");
    }
}
```

HTH. Note access modifiers omitted.

Comment: Marc Gravell's change is simpler and seems fine. I'm in the habit of binding everything to BindingSource objects on general principles; it's there, it's built for this purpose, might as well use it.

Comment: BindingSource acts purely as a level of abstraction; you can bind directly to both instances and lists.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *purely* as a level of abstraction; there's actual code in BindingSource that does things, such as manage currency.

Comment: Currency is managed by a currency manager, which you get by default when binding to an `IList`/`IListSource`; you simply get *more* control with `BindingSource`. So if you need it, great! `BindingSource` also provides points to control creation of new items for lists, but you can do that in many other ways, including simply implementing the right `ComponentModel` interfaces.

Comment: Indeed. You get more control, BindingSource is cheap to implement, it's part of the standard framework and built precisely for that purpose. I agree: you don't *have* to use BindingSource, but for the above reasons, my preference is to use it unless there's a compelling reason not to.

Answer (score 4):

One of the things I like to do is to create "presentation" layer for the form.  It is in this layer that I declare the properties that are bound to the controls on the form.  In this case, the control is a text box.

In this example I have a form with a textbox to display an IP Address

[image]

We now create the binding source through the textbox properties.  Select DataBindings->Text.  Click the down arrow; select 'Add Project Data Source'.

[image]

This starts up that Data Source wizard.  Select Object. Hit 'Next'.

[image]

Now select the class that has the property that will be bounded to the text box.  In this example, I chose *PNetworkOptions*.  Select Finish to end the wizard.  The BindingSource will not be created.

[image]

The next step is to select the actual property from the bound class.  From DataBindings->Text, select the downarrow and select the property name that will be bound to the textbox.

[image]

In the class that has your property, INotifyPropertyChanged must implemented for 2-way communication for IP Address field

```
public class PNetworkOptions : IBaseInterface, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _IPAddress;


    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }

    public string IPAddress
    {
        get { return _IPAddress; }
        set
        {
            if (value != null && value != _IPAddress)
            {
                _IPAddress = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IPAddress");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the form constructor, we have to specifically define the binding

```
Binding IPAddressbinding = mskTxtIPAddress.DataBindings.Add("Text", _NetOptions, "IPAddress",true,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```