# how can I bind a string property to a ToolStripTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

My question, I believe, is rooted in the fact that while a `TextBox` is an `IBindableComponent`, a `ToolStripTextBox` is not.

I'm looking to do simple binding with `ToolStripTextBox` as described in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497489/c-binding-textbox-to-an-integer).

```
public int Unit {get;set;} 
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  toolStripTextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", this, "Unit"); 
}
```

Currently I am doing this:

```
public string SendToEmail {
 get{
  return _sendToEmail.Text;
 }
 set {
  _sendToEmail.Text = value;
 }
}
```

So right now I'm getting two way synch but it is not loosely coupled.

**QUESTION**: Is there a .NET class that encapsulates the name of a property two classes and monitors for changes going one or both directions, (using reflection?) pushing the values between?  Or is there a simpler way to think about it?

Answer (score 4):

Use the TextBox property of the ToolStripTextBox to do your databinding.  This is a full-blow TextBox control giving you access to the DataBinding that you want.

```
// this is NOT the same code as above, note the TextBox property in use.
this.toolStripTextBox1.TextBox.DataBindings.Add(...);
```