# Databinding issue in C#

Tags: c#, data-binding

I have an issue with DataBindings in C#.

I have a BindingSource with it's DataSource set to a DataRowView

I then use the binding source to set all the databinding for my controls.

Here is my code:

```
bsDataRecord.DataSource = myDataRow; //bsDataRecord is a BindingSource and myDataRow is a DataRowView
//Add Databinding to my controls
dateNextDate.DataBindings.Add("Value", bsDataRecord, "Next_Date", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged); //DateTimePicker
textInformation.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsDataRecord, "Information", false); //TextBox
//more controls, etc
```

My databindings all work fine. So as I select the control and enter a value, myDataRow is updated.

My problems occurs when I try to set a control's value in code e.g.

```
textInformation.Text="Test";
```

When I do this myDataRow isn't updated. The only way I can get myDataRow to update is to give the control that I've updated focus.

Hope that makes sense!? Anybody got any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

I'm using c#.Net 4.0.

Comment: Hope this be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497489/c-sharp-binding-textbox-to-an-integer

Comment: Why not doing the opposite? Update the data and the control should show the new value.

Comment: I did try that but that was update the RowState of my data row to modified even after I'd saved and accepted changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After problematically setting a property of the data source, you need to get the controls to reread their values from the datasource. Often a simple call to

```
dataBindingSource.ResetBindings(false); // false for value change not schema change
```

But you could also per control use this:

```
foreach (Binding b in myControl.DataBindings) b.ReadValue();
```

Binding.ReadValue() causes the control's bound property to be set to the data source value

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you update a (non-two-way)binding's target "by hand", that breaks the binding and it will not work anymore. This is normal behaviour.

So make your binding two-way to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It that just a property that I can set then?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment :/

Comment: How do you make a two-way binding?